# Database migration from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

We are planning to migrate our production databases from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008. Do we need to create all existing logins for all databases in the new instance? Is there any script which will move users and respective logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a set of procedures called sp_help_revlogin and sp_hexadecimal that will script out the logins, their hashed passwords and their respective SID's.

Here is the script for 2005-2008. Execute this against your old server to create the procs and then run "exec sp_help_revlogin" against master and it will script out everything to add those logins to another instance.

Cheers!

```
USE master
GO 

IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_hexadecimal') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_hexadecimal
    @binvalue varbinary(256),
    @hexvalue varchar (514) OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @charvalue varchar (514)
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @length int
DECLARE @hexstring char(16)
SELECT @charvalue = '0x'
SELECT @i = 1
SELECT @length = DATALENGTH (@binvalue)
SELECT @hexstring = '0123456789ABCDEF'
WHILE (@i <= @length)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tempint int
  DECLARE @firstint int
  DECLARE @secondint int
  SELECT @tempint = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@binvalue,@i,1))
  SELECT @firstint = FLOOR(@tempint/16)
  SELECT @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16)
  SELECT @charvalue = @charvalue +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) +
    SUBSTRING(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1)
  SELECT @i = @i + 1
END
SELECT @hexvalue = @charvalue
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('sp_help_revlogin') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_help_revlogin @login_name sysname = NULL AS
DECLARE @name sysname
DECLARE @type varchar (1)
DECLARE @hasaccess int
DECLARE @denylogin int
DECLARE @is_disabled int
DECLARE @PWD_varbinary  varbinary (256)
DECLARE @PWD_string  varchar (514)
DECLARE @SID_varbinary varbinary (85)
DECLARE @SID_string varchar (514)
DECLARE @tmpstr  varchar (1024)
DECLARE @is_policy_checked varchar (3)
DECLARE @is_expiration_checked varchar (3)

IF (@login_name IS NULL)
  DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR
      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin
        FROM sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l ON ( l.name = p.name )
        WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name <> 'sa'
ELSE
  DECLARE login_curs CURSOR FOR
      SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin
        FROM sys.server_principals p LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins l ON ( l.name = p.name )
        WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) AND p.name = @login_name
OPEN login_curs
FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @hasaccess, @denylogin
IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
  CLOSE login_curs
  DEALLOCATE login_curs
  RETURN -1
END
SET @tmpstr = '/* sp_help_revlogin script '
PRINT @tmpstr
SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'
PRINT @tmpstr
PRINT ''
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
  IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
  BEGIN
    PRINT ''
    SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name
    PRINT @tmpstr

    IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
    BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group
      SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS'
    END
    ELSE BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
        -- obtain password and sid
        SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
        EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary, @SID_string OUT

        -- obtain password policy state
        SELECT @is_policy_checked =
            CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END
            FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name
        SELECT @is_expiration_checked =
            CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END
            FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = @name

        SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
            + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string
            + ' HASHED, SID = ' + @SID_string

        IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
        END
        IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
        END
    END

    IF (@denylogin = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is denied access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END
    ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
    BEGIN -- login has exists but does not have access
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
    END

    IF (@is_disabled = 1)
    BEGIN -- login is disabled
      SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
    END

    PRINT @tmpstr
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @hasaccess, @denylogin
  END
CLOSE login_curs
DEALLOCATE login_curs

RETURN 0
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an in-place upgrade. There is a whitepaper on this topic from Microsoft: [SQL Server 2005 to 2008 Upgrade Whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/3/D/53D72434-7BD5-41C6-A806-8212C1B0DCA1/SQL%20Server%202005%20to%202008%20Upgrade%20White%20Paper.docx) which highlights the tools at your disposal and possible upgrade strategies. Doing an in-place upgrade will save all logins, all SQL Agent jobs, maintenanc eplans, database mail configurations and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this same migration. Since the Sids change between SQL instances, I had to script all the logins and database users for each database as well as the permissions each user should have.  That way I only had to run the script once after the databases are restored to the new server, and all permissions will work as they did on your old instance.

There may be automatic ways, but T-SQL has always served me well in this task.